# JVM stuck for seconds to hours

Tags: java, jvm, jstack

I see that my applications (running on a Linux VM) seem to freeze for minutes up to hours!

In that time it is not responsive, even VisualVM loses the connection during that time. And also to `jstack` the JVM does not response.

My code is full of log-statements due to that problem. Somewhere in my code I even have two log statements next to each other.

```
logger.error("DEBUG 1");
logger.error("DEBUG 2");
```

These lines appear 2 minutes(!) apart in the log file.

The Java version I use is

```
openjdk version "17.0.8.1" 2023-08-24
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.8.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.8.1+1, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas how I could determine the problem here?

Comment: Maybe any other process running in the VM which is eating the ram. Check the free ram/heap size during application run

Comment: I agree, this is more likely a problem with another process blocking the resources than the JVM itself.

Comment: Maybe the log handler itself is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the Linux VM is not suspended, or running on an overcommitted host (and thus not getting enough CPU)?

Comment: The trigger of this Situation was a concurrent write access to a sqlite-databse via Hibernate. I properly synchronized this part of the code and now it is working. But I'm still not sure how this can block every Thread(Even Timers!)